# What features and resources of Apache APISIX are not dynamically loadable?

Tags: gateway, apache-apisix

Apache APISIX is dynamic in nature. What are the resources and features in APISIX that can and cannot be loaded dynamically, and why can't these resources be loaded dynamically?